# Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 28, Exercise B4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Prove that $\{f : f$ is a constant on the interval $[0,1]\}$ is a subspace of $\mathscr{F}(R)$.

This doesn't seem true. Let $U=\{f : f$ is a constant on the interval $[0,1]\}$.
Obviously $U\subseteq \mathscr{F}(R)$.
For every $k\in R$ and $f\in U$, $kf(x)$ is not necessarily a constant on the interval $[0,1]$.
Since $U$ is not closed with respective to scalar multiplication, $U$ is not a subspace of $\mathscr{F}(R)$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is $k\cdot f(x)$ non constant in $[0,1]$? Suppose $f(y)=c$ for $y\in [0,1],$ then $k\cdot f(y)=k\cdot c$ which is constant in $[0,1].$

Comment: Example: $k=100, f(x)=0.5$.  Then $k\cdot f(x)=50$.

Comment: @hchar : What is nonconstant about "$50$"?

Comment: $50$ is a constant but not on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: At first I thought you had troubles with the definition of "constant," but now I suspect it's with the word "on". "Constant on the interval $[a, b]$" is an adjectival phrase that can be applied to functions, not to numbers. On the other hand, a 
"constant **in** the interval $[a,b]$" is a single number. The function defined on the whole real line by $f(x) = 50$ for every $x$ is constant on the interval $[0,1]$ (and elsewhere as well). The number $50$, however, is not a constant **in** the interval $[0, 1]$, because it's larger than $1$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are saying "on the interval $[0,1]$" means the domain of the function $f$ is the interval $[0,1]$", whereas the range of $f$ is an arbitrary constant $c\in R$.  Make sense.

Comment: Close: "$f$ constant on the interval" means "for any $u, v$ in the interval, we have $f(u) = f(v)$. It's possible for the domain of a function to be much larger than some interval on which it's constant. An example helps: For instance, the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &  x \le 0 \\ x^2 & x > 0 \end{cases}$ is constant on the interval $[-3, -1]$ (or any other interval containing only non-positive numbers), but its *domain* is the whole real line.

Comment: Yup; make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I guess $R=\Bbb R$ and $V:=\mathcal F(R)$ denotes the $\Bbb R$-vector space of functions $\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ with *pointwise* scalar multiplication and addition.

Then $U:=\{f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R\mid f \text{ constant on }[0,1]\}$ is a subspace of $V$. Indeed, given $f,g\in U$ (with $f(x)=k, g(x)=l$ for all $x\in[0,1]$) and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ we find that $$(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x) = \alpha k$$ and $$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x) = k+l$$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Since $0$ is constant on $[0,1]$ this shows the claim.